# Add button against each record on django admin change list page?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-admin

I want to add a button against each row on django admin change list page. When that button is clicked, i want to make entries in some database table(all this happens on the backend) and after that the button should be disabled on the same page against that row.

How can i achieve this? I have searched a lot button there is no solution available.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to edit the `changelist_result_list` template at the point where the result items are generated (near the bottom) to add an element that provokes a request. For example:

```
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
    {% for item in result %}
        {{ item }}
        <!-- NEW STUFF --->
        {% if forloop.last %}
            <td>{% if pk %}<a href="do_things_with_object_{{pk}}">CLICK ME</a>{% endif %}</td>
        {% endif%}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

(Don't forget to also update the table headers further up)
You are going to have to provide a template context variable for `{{pk}}` by messing with the templatetag `result_list` in `django.contrib.admin.template_tags.admin_list` -- meaning, you are creating [your own templatetag](http://file:///I:/Python/venv/djangofun/django-docs-2.0-en/howto/custom-template-tags.html) for this.

Then you need to set up a view and an url conf to handle the request the links send.
Let's say you're at `foo/bar` and click on the link for the row with `pk=2`. A GET request will be send for `foo/bar/do_things_with_object_2`.
Your url conf needs to capture the pk (and the model, here: `bar`) and your view needs to do whatever it is you want on the object.